# What is the best way to save information between runs of plugin?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, plugins, intellij-plugin

I'm looking for the best way to save user information between two runs of a Plugin for IntelliJ.

What is the best way to do that?

are there special tools of IntelliJ to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For simple things you can use **com.intellij.ide.util.PropertiesComponent** interface.
If it's not enough, implement **com.intellij.openapi.components.PersistentStateComponent** interface.

More information is available [here](http://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/basics/persisting_state_of_components.html).